# Overriding a mongoose model method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have the following express route:

```
app.post('/users/me',(req, res) => {
  var body =  req.body.email;
  User.find({
    email: body
  }).then((user) => {
    res.send({user});
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});
```

On my User model I have the following method which limits results returned to email and _id:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    var user = this;
    var userObject = user.toObject();

    return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email']);
};
```

In most of my routes that is exactly what I want however in this particular route I would like to return additional fields. How can I override\bypass the model method and have my fields returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can create an additional method and call it in the res.send().
For example if I wanted to add Password as part of the return I can create a new Method:

```
UserSchema.methods.toPrivateJSON = function () {
    var user = this;
    var userObject = user.toObject();
    return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email', 'activeAccount', 'password']);

};
```

Then in my route when I return the user object I call

```
res.send(user.toPrivateJSON());
```

This will invoke the `toPrivateJSON()` method and return the additional fields needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/users/me',(req, res) => {
  var body =  req.body.email;
  User.find({
    email: body
  }).then((user) => {
    user.private = true; //tells to model method to include additional fields
    res.send({user});
  }, (e) => {
    res.status(400).send(e);
  });
});
```

Then in the model method:

```
UserSchema.methods.toJSON = function () {
    var user = this;
    var userObject = user.toObject();
    if(user.private)
      return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email', 'additionalField']);
    else
      return _.pick(userObject, ['_id', 'email']);
};
```

Comment: This is not working. i added some conole logging and I see that in the model method the if(user.private) is being returned false so skipping to the else.

Comment: this should work with single object, but when multiple objects are returned then one has to iterate over each object to set `private` value

Answer (score 0):

You can also change the override value from not true to true in your:C:\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js
i.e..
if (_mongoose.models.hasOwnProperty(name) && options.cache !== false && overwriteModels !== true)
change !===true to ===true

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?